Autoit Window security window is not being recognized
So, I have a script where I am using shell execute to open an excel file and a window security popup shows up saying to enter your network credentials. The issue I am having is that i am not able to send in the password in the input field. I have tried using win exists, win activate, winwaitactive to have focus on the window but it still doesnt work. It doesnt input the password.  Here is the code I tried. The path to file is a network path in file explorer so I don't know if that has anything to do with it.
Shell Execute
("path to file")
If Win Exists("Windows Security") Then
Sleep(2000)
Send("password")
EndIf
If not Win Exists("Windows Security") Then
Continue on
Endif

Do you know why Windows Security pops up when accessing the spreadsheet file? Maybe it would be better to simply save the network credentials: Add Windows Credentials

Not entirely sure if the UAC can be interacted with but I would try a couple adjustments. Wait for the window to be active and then send the keystrokes raw.
ShellExecute("path to file")
$win = WinWaitActive("Windows Security", "", 2) ;Waits 2 seconds for window to activate
If $win <> 0 Then Send("password", 1) ;If window was found send password, added optional parameter to send keys raw
Continue on
;If $win = 0 Then do stuff ;Alternative for if timeout occurred and Windows Security was not activated
Endif

